# WiringPi ISR is not called although interrupts occur?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, interrupt, interrupt-handling, wiringpi

I have connected GPIO Pin 17(in WiringPi Pin17 = Pin0) of my raspberry pi 1 with an interrupt source (an IR-LEDemitter/receiver which triggers an interrupt whenever the IR ray gets interrupted by some obstacle). For setting up the ISR, I have been using the WiringPi library (I have already tried it with the pigpio library as well, but I have the same problem there as well).
To verify that I am actually receiving interrupts on Pin17, I have checked it with my logic analyzer, and there are definitely some interrupts occuring on this pin as you can see:[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include "MCP3008Driver.h"
#include "DHT11.h"

#define INT_PIN 0

volatile int eventCounter = 0;

void myInterrupt(void){
    printf("hello ISR!\n");
    eventCounter++;
}

volatile sig_atomic_t stopFlag = 0;
static void stopHandler(int sign) { /* can be called asynchronously */
    stopFlag = 1; /* set flag */
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, stopHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM, stopHandler);

    // sets up the wiringPi library
    if (wiringPiSetup () < 0) {
        printf("Unable to setup wiring pi\n");
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to setup wiringPi: %s\n", strerror 
(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // set Pin 17/0 to generate an interrupt on high-to-low transitions
    // and attach myInterrupt() to the interrupt
    if(wiringPiISR(INT_PIN, INT_EDGE_FALLING, &myInterrupt) < 0){
        printf("unable to setup ISR\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to setup ISR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    DHT11_data data;
    configureSPI();

    while(1){
        if(stopFlag){
            printf("\n Ctrl-C signal caught! \n");
            printf("Closing application. \n");
            return 0;
        }

        //read_dht_data(&data);
        int analogBoiler = readChannel(0);
        int analogHeater = readChannel(1);
        int analogPress = readChannel(2);
        int analogACS712 = readChannel(3);
        int analogDynamo = readChannel(4);
        printf("Channel 0 / Boiler = %f\n", evaluateChannelValue(ePT100_BOILER, analogBoiler));
        printf("Channel 1 / Heater = %f\n", evaluateChannelValue(ePT100_HEATER, analogHeater));
        printf("Channel 2 / Pressure = %f\n", evaluateChannelValue(ePRESS, analogPress));
        printf("Channel 3 / Power ACS712 = %f\n", evaluateChannelValue(eACS712, analogACS712));
        printf("Channel 4 / Power Dynamo = %f\n", evaluateChannelValue(eDYNAMO, analogDynamo));
        //printf("Humidity Environment: %f\n", data.humidity);
         //printf("Temperature (Celsius) Environment: %f\n", data.temp_celsius);

        // display counter value every second.
        printf("%d\n", eventCounter);



        sleep(5);  
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

The methods wiringPiSetup and wiringPiISR are successfully called and are not returning an error.

I am building this example the the following linking options: -lwiringPi -lm -lpthread. Maybe I am missing a linking option?

I have been using [this code here](http://raspberrypihobbyist.blogspot.com/2015/01/gpio-interrupts-using-wiringpi.html) as a reference. So what am I doing wrong here? Thank you for any advice you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why but I found that removing the unary operator in front of the function call input to `wiringPiISR` solved my problems.

So instead of calling

`wiringPiISR(INT_PIN, INT_FALLING_EDGE, &MyInterrupt)`

call

`wiringPiISR(INT_PIN, INT_FALLING_EDGE, MyInterrupt)`

My guess is that this has something to do with the fact the `wiringPiISR` is taking that argument as pointer (*function) so putting the address of call in front of it causes something weird to happen when it goes to try and call the `MyInterrupt` function, for me it caused my program to crash!

Hope this helps / maybe someone else will be able to elaborate more on why this would happen.